# PHP riddle about variable type

Tags: php, variables, types, casting

```
<?php

$x = ?

if ($x == "1") print "1";
if ($x == "2") print "2";
if ($x == "3") print "3";

?>
```

What must be the **$x** to print output `"123"` ?

You may assign **$x** value only once.

Comment: @OneTrickPony Gratification ? :) -May be some upvotes if this were an answer

Comment: Well, this isn't a real question, is it? Since you know the answer...

Comment: @OneTrickPony there are a lot of Q in this site with a riddle conquest are they real questions?

Comment: I like riddles. You should propose them on meta ;)

Comment: codegolf.stackexchange.com accepts "programming puzzles", although you'd have to check with them whether this sort (which doesn't involve writing code) are on-topic.

Comment: @Wooble thank you for a piece of advice

Comment: @OneTrickPony ok, thanks! next time I will make the right solution where to post such questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x = true
```

Solution: *always* use `===`. I've never seen a case where `==` was absolutely necessary.

Add this as an inspection rule to your IDE.

Comment: I don't even use PHP :) I like more ASP.NET, just make a riddle.